# gradle duplicate class found when adding tika dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, apache-tika

I have an Android Java project. When I add these two lines to my `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-langdetect-optimaize:2.8.0'
   implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-core:2.8.0'
   ...
}
```

After build I have this error:
`Duplicate class found`.

I just wanted to add a few lines of [code](https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/Language.java)

```
import org.apache.tika.langdetect.optimaize.OptimaizeLangDetector;
import org.apache.tika.language.detect.LanguageDetector;
import org.apache.tika.language.detect.LanguageResult;
...
LanguageDetector detector = new OptimaizeLangDetector().loadModels();
LanguageResult result =
        detector.detect("Alla människor är födda fria och lika i värde och rättigheter.");

    String detected_language = result.getLanguage();
```

Did I added wrong dependencies?